# how to change the header title dynamically in tableview in viewForHeaderInSection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to set the title name in tableview header. im use this in code in

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section  function
{
   IView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    UILabel *lbl_header = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    lbl_header.tag=1000001;
    lbl_header.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl_header.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255 green:204.0/255 blue:204.0/255 alpha:1.0];
    lbl_header.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Regular" size:20];

    ////  get the title name from subclass view controller 

    HOAViewController *obj_hoaview_controll = [[HOAViewController alloc]init];
    [obj_hoaview_controll fun_get_login_email_id];


    lbl_header.text = str_email_id1;//[udf_value objectForKey:@"StrEmailGet"];


    if (section == 0)
    {
         [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255 green:102.0/255 blue:102.0/255 alpha:1.0]];
        //lbl_header.text = [udf_value objectForKey:@"StrEmailGet"];
    }
    else
    {
         [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    [headerView addSubview:lbl_header];
    return headerView;
}
```

Thanks for reply....

Comment: Your question is unclear. The code you posted already sets the header's title (`lbl_header.text = str_email_id1;`). What is your question really asking?

Comment: str_email_id1 is string object and store the title name in that.

Answer (score 6):

Use [titleForHeaderInSection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW13), from UITableViewDataSource protocol. Make sure that `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is also implemented well.

**Sample:**

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (section == 0)
    return @"Title1";
   else if (section == 1)
    return @"Title2";
}
```

Comment: title name get from one class to another class here code for that HOAViewController *obj_hoaview_controll = [[HOAViewController alloc]init];
    [obj_hoaview_controll fun_get_login_email_id];.

Comment: That can be handled using your logic but within above function and it will work. If it does, please mark the answer as correct (the checkmark sign)

Comment: the title name get from one class to another class and finally in the lbl_header.text object. i got the title name from sub class and how to  reload the viewForHeaderInSection function or call the viewForHeaderInSection in that class.

Comment: Try [tableview reloadSectionIndexTitles];

Comment: thank for reply, i need to set the title in dynamic from one class to another class through object.

Comment: What I meant is, get it from your own processing from other class. Once you know you have the title,call [tableView  reloadSectionIndexTitles];

Comment: im set the title code in viewForHeaderInSection function but this function only once call when the view controller loading lbl_header.text = [udf_value objectForKey:@"StrEmailGet"]; through user default object. not write code in titleForHeaderInSection function